# Invalid for() loop sequence

Tags: r

I'm trying to use as.name(x) to refer to a list to input into a function. Here's an example of my simplified version of my stats function followed by the for loop I'm using to output all the data at once.

```
get<-function(data,x) {
  for (i in x) {
    lm(as.formula(paste(i,'~',variable)),data)
  }
}
lists<-c("a","b","c") 
# where each of a, b, and c are lists that refer to column names of my data
for (j in lists) {
  get(data,as.name(j))
  }
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in for (i in x) { : invalid for() loop sequence
```

If I just do get(data,a) each time it works but not when I try and do a loop.

Comment: My guess is that if you're doing `paste(i,'~',variable)` then you don't need `as.name(j)`. Just do `get(data, j)`. BTW, `get` is a really bad name for a function, it already is one of `base R`. And so is `data`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data to repro the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are each of `a`, `b` and `c` a list that contains only one value? I ask because your `lm()` formula has `i` on the left hand side, and can only be a vector.

If that's the case, then replacing `as.name(j)` with `j` should make your code work.

Comment: They're lists that contain multiple column names that refer to my data.

Didn't realize that the paste made the as.name useless. This worked!